# Using confirm() inside jQuery focus event handler prevents change event triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I am interested in why this doesn't work, tried it in a variety of jQuery versions.

The fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/6nLej9ut/

```
$('#override').on('focus', function(e) {
    $(this).blur();
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        if(!confirm('You will lose any changes you have made if you proceed?')) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
});

$('#override').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('#label').css('font-weight', 'bold');
    }
    else {
        $('#label').css('font-weight', 'normal');
    }
});
```

Specifically, when the user tries to uncheck the checkbox, the change event never fires, I've tried a number of variations of this and it seems that calling confirm() inside a focus event handler prevents a change event from triggering.

Does anyone know if this is a jQuery bug, known expected behaviour or I'm just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
var ok = confirm('You will lose any changes you have made if you proceed?');
if (!ok) {
// trigger
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to prevent the focus event, try to handle click event or you must listen for "change" event and handle everything yourself.

You can safely prevent user actions ( like "click" ) before it trigger "change" event using "confirm"ation like:

```
$('#override').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).blur();
    if ( !$(this).is(":checked") ) {
        if (!confirm('You will lose any changes you have made if you proceed?')) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

try to understand yourself:

```
$('#override').on('click focus change', function(e) {
    console.log('event type: ', e.type);
});
```

and

```
$('#override').on('click change', function(e) {
    //e.preventDefault(); // toggle me and check the console for "change" event
    console.log(e.type);
});
```